# Orthogonal trajectories in complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, orthogonality

I stumbled with this problem in an old book that has been bothering me last days. Could you help me with this?

Be $f(x + iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ an holomorphic function. Prove that level curves $u(x,y) = c, v(x,y)=k$ are two families of orthogonal trajectories.

Comment: Non constant, presumably?

Comment: Don't understand.

Comment: If $u$ and $v$ are constants, the level sets degenerate. But this is mostly a nitpick. Hint: use Cauchy-Riemann.

Comment: @IvoTerek: The idea is to start the OP thinking rather than just a nitpick... Plus, it is not entirely trivial, for example $f(z)=z^2$ at $z=0$.

Comment: Yes yes, but since OP also used the differential equations tag, I'm guessing the point of the exercise is to just do the one-line computation, which works even if u and v are constants, but then we get something either vacuously true (empty level sets) or with no relevant geometrical interpretation (the gradients are zero) -- and then thinking about whether the level sets are empty or not might not really help with the computation.

Comment: @IvoTerek: Perhaps I am overthinking it, but it seems to me one needs to first establish that $u(x,y)=k$ defines a suitable curve in the first place.

Comment: If OP wants to go into that level of detail (my point is that I think this is not the case) then yes, of course, we need to assume that u and v are non-constant :)

Comment: @IvoTerek: Perhaps. Certainly I found a sort of hand waving in many complex analysis texts to be initially confusing in particular when dealing with curves.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\neq0$ on some interval. You have 
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\times 1+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\times y'(x)=0,
$$
so (writing $y_1$ to represent the first curve)
$$
y_1'(x)=-\frac{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}}.
$$
Similarly, and using Cauchy-Riemann,
$$
y_2'(x)=-\frac{\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}}=-\frac{-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}}=-\frac1{y_1'(x)}.
$$

Comment: Are you using Implicit Function Theorem? Can you use it? (Knowing requirements as F(x,y) = 0, F of class one, etc)

Comment: The functions $u,v$ are harmonic (that's your hypothesis), so they are infinitely differentiable.